# c# Can't Append text to existing file

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to append some text to an existing TEXT file using c#.  I have tried the four different ways below and it isn't working.  This does work on my machine at home, but not on my desktop here at work (so I'm assuming it's something different between the two PCs and not the c# code.)  I've looked at the permissions on this text file and everything seems fine.  I certainly have the correct rights to write to this file.  They are both runnings Windows 10.  Both machines are running Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition version 16.11.3.  I'm an Administrator on both machines.

```
var thePath = "C:\\Temp\\Logs\\MyTextFile.txt";

File.AppendAllText(thePath, "New Data" + Environment.NewLine);

File.AppendAllLines(thePath, new [] { "New Data" });

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(thePath, true))
{
    sw.WriteLine("New Data");
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}

using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.AppendText(thePath))
{
    sw2.WriteLine("New Data");
    sw2.Flush();
    sw2.Close();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Is UAC enabled on both machines? Is your application running elevated on both machines?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with the code you wrote. You should post your error message or debug it. `File.AppendAllText(thePath, "New Data" + Environment.NewLine);` itself should work however it will just add to the same line and not give you a new line.

Comment: I think the calls to `Flush` and `Close` are unneeded since you have a `using` statement which should Flush and Close the StreamWriters for you.
Try writing to somewhere you are more likely to have write privileges, like the Documents directory for the current user.

Comment: hmm... company security policies can be tricky when accessing "C:\" (if Temp was created with another aoocunt than yours, and so on...). Can you test it in the %Appdata% (the logged-on user can do 'everything' here) just to be sure? ``File.AppendAlltext`` should be fine - if the permissions fit :-)

Comment: You could try creating the file yourself and writing to it and then running this code.  By creating the file yourself, it will rule out (or confirm) whether the issue is down to permissions. Not a fix but may enable you to focus on the real cause.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some more checking on Google, the issue turned out to be Comodo was blocking my machine from writing to that drive/folder.  Once we turned this off (temporarily) it worked just great.  Thanks for any and all input.